# There was a rumor + is/was

Tags: tenses, sequence-of-tenses, past-vs-present

Could anyone tell me if the sentence "There was a rumor that Citibank is in debt." is grammatically correct ?

Please advise me. Some say it is correct while others say it is ungrammatical. I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone is thinking of the alleged rule (I was taught Latin names for these English forms, so *oratio obliqua*) whereby the tense of the main verb forces the same tense in subordinate clauses. Andrew Leach says it doesn't exist, but perhaps I and your corrector are not the only ones who think it does. "He thinks she is pretty", but "He told her that she WAS pretty". So technically it should be, according to this school of misunderstood Latinity, "There was a rumour that Citibank WAS in debt", but if it still *is* in debt, one might decide to sacrifice the rule for the precision.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if its not still in a debt, then will it be correct to say "There was a rumor that Citibank is in debt." ?

Comment: Not properly, no, but most people won't care. The rule to which I referred is probably known only to wrinklies and young fogeys.

Comment: There is no rule in English [unlike Latin] which forces the tense of subordinate clauses to be the same as the main clause, because -- as you say -- sometimes the "rule" reduces precision. I'm unclear as to whether this answer says English does have the Latin rule, or does not.

Comment: @Andrew. Oh dear, another victim of the schoolmasters who imposed the Latin rules. I really and truly believed this. Better edit.

Comment: @DavidPugh I had a Latinate English master, too. I still position adverbs not to split infinitives. (Did you see what I did there?) Adverb position is usually less crucial than what may be implied or inferred from changing tense in a subordinate clause, though.

Comment: @Andrew. I would never force "boldly to go" on anyone else, but I just can't write "to boldly go" myself. My fingers declare industrial action.

Comment: @AndrewLeach -- Yes certainly these are not rules. It just serves as a basic guideline. So if Citibank is not still in a debt then is it correct to say "There was a rumor that Citibank is in debt." ?

Comment: That question has already been answered more than once.

Comment: Sir with all due respect, could you please answer it once more.

Comment: @AndrewLeach -- I know that a past tense in the main clause CAN be followed by the present tense in a subordinate clause. But if there is a situation where Citibank is not in a debt at the time of narrating then here will it be correct to say "There is a rumor that Citibank IS in a debt." ?               Okay let me put it the other way - Suppose I'm narrating a past incident (incident which happened a year ago) to my friend and in which one of the sentence goes like "There was a rumor that Citibank is in debt." So here is 'is' correct or do I need to use 'was' instead ?

Comment: @iamRR If Citibank is no longer in debt, then DO NOT USE *is*. Say *A year ago there was a rumour that Citibank WAS in debt*. The example I gave you was of a meeting an hour ago discussing present conditions - *There was a rumour circulating at the meeting that Citibank is in debt*. That is an entirely different situation.

Comment: @WS2 -- But earlier you said that "I see nothing wrng in it."

Comment: @iamRR I am sorry if I may have misled you. The confusion here is about there being a 'rumour'. You may well know that Citibank is not in debt, but there could still be a rumour that 'it is in debt'. *I knew it to be wrong but there was a rumour that Citibank is in debt*.

Comment: So does that mean that 'is' can never be used ?

Answer (score 3):

***There was a rumour (at the meeting I just attended) that Brokenshire is (currently) in debt.***

That would seem to me to be a perfectly valid construction.

But ***Six moths ago there was a rumour circulating that Brokenshire was (then) in debt***.

This is entirely a question of which tenses sound right in the circumstances. But they do not have to match, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My intention of asking question is, if Citibank is not in a debt and I know it for a fact then under this circumstance, will it be correct to say "There was a rumor that Citibank is in debt." ?

Comment: @iamRR I see nothing at all wrong with that.

Comment: Okay let me put it the other way. Suppose I'm narrating a past incident (incident which happened a year ago) to my friend and in which one of the sentence goes like "There was a rumor that Citibank is in debt."   So here is 'is' correct or do I need to use 'was' instead ?

Comment: Or will it be correct to say " A year ago there was a rumor that Citibank IS in a debt." ?

Comment: @iamRR: Whatever the merits of the tenses, you should desist from saying "is in a debt."

Comment: @DavidPugh-- I agree with you but why Andrew Leach keeps on stressing that 'is' is correct under all situations ?

Comment: @Andrew Leach -- Why on earth don't you reply. I'm getting too confused.

Comment: @DavidPugh -- you say in your second message of this conversation that we can't use 'is' if Citibank is not still in a debt. And at the same time you say that this rule is 'old fashioned'. So what am I to understand by this, does that mean the sentenec can be grammatically correct even if the person uses 'is' under the condition that Citibank is not in a debt ?

Comment: @iamRR people do not speak to each other in disjointed isolated sentences. Context, previous shared information, and common knowledge, will usually tell the listener if the bank was in debt a year ago or if it still is. "There was a rumour that Citibank was in debt" could mean the bank is no longer in debt OR  I don't know if the bank is currently in debt. I might simply be sharing information. If I know for a fact that Citibank IS in debt then I would say: "[Did you know] Citibank is in debt, the first time I heard about it was a year ago/rumours began to spread a year ago."

Comment: @Mari-LouA -  Let's say Citibank is no longer in debt and there is no such rumor going on (rumor was in the past ), then under this condition can we use 'is' ? All in all let me ask you, if the situation is not still true then can we use present tense in a subordinate clause ? For example, Today I meet Bob and Bob says to me, "I am feeling hungry." Two days later I meet another friend Kobe and Kobe asks "What did Bob say to you when you last met ?" I reply "Bob said that he is/was feeling hungry. Here can 'is' be used ever ?

Comment: @iamRR you don't catch me out on this one. You've asked [this question yesterday](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/249671/44619) and the user oerkelens explained perfectly in his answer. You also upvoted AND accepted his explanation. So, explain to me why you are unsatisfied with the answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- I'm satisfied with his answer. You see the whole issue began few days back when I asked a question "Can present tense in a subordinate clause be followed by the last tense in the main clause ?" Someone replied "Yes, there is no such limitation."  So does that mean that even if what was said is not still true then, can we use present tense in a subordinate clause ?

Comment: @Mari-LouA --As in this example  For example, Today I meet X and X says to me, "I am feeling hungry." Two days later I meet another friend Y and Y asks "What did X say to you when you last met ?" I reply "X said that he is/was feeling hungry. Here can 'is' be used ever ?

Comment: So, if you're satisfied with the answer given, why are you still querying about your example? You have your answer, I could not explain it better myself. I have also attempted to explain to you that in real life we will understand the context, and if necessary we can ask for clarifications. A short verbal exchange might take less than a minute. This fascination of yours with indirect/reported speech tells me that you will never be happy with answers that basically say *it depends*. Your English is also *very* good...

Comment: Then what is this forum for when you can't help others ?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I believe you deserve commendation for your patience. I wish I could propose you for an award.